# How to get Flow to recognize DOM objects

Tags: flowtype

If I use the online [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAJnAxgVwLYCmAdgC4DcQA) tool and simply write `document`; I get the error "Cannot resolve name `document`." How can I get it to recognize DOM objects like `document`, `window`, and other objects that are present in the browser? Is there a libdef I need to import? I clearly see that Flow has a [dom.js](https://github.com/facebook/flow/tree/master/lib) but how would I reference that?

Comment: It seems that there’s an issue https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5442

Comment: This is only an issue in the playground. Flow binaries will have this included, but we omitted some library definitions from the playground in order to improve initialization times.